# How to detect screen change in class component with navigation v6?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I just want to clear the state when you move to any other screen in my class component when I'm using navigation v6 (I saw some coments about function component but not class), so I will explain briefly

I did a clean state function in my Body component

```
class InputBody extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fields: JSON.parse(this.props.route).message,
    };       
  }

  reset () {
    this.setState({});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        {Object.keys(JSON.parse(this.props.route).message).length > 0 ? (
          <FieldArraysForm all={JSON.parse(this.props.route).message} resetForm={reset} native={this.props} />
        ) : (
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#eb6b09" />
        )}
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

And then I call it in my fields array component

```
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
class FieldArraysForm extends Component {
  render() {
    const {handleSubmit} = this.props.native;
    // event listener
    const getFields = async (values) => {
      return sleep(500).then(() => {       
        console.log(JSON.stringify(values))
        this.props.resetForm();
      })
    }
    return (
      <Form>
        {this.props.all.map((item) => (
          <Field
            key={item._id}
            name={`customInput.${item._id}`}
            component={RenderField}
            label={item.field}
            type={item.typeFieldAltText}
          />
        ))}
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleSubmit(getFields)}>
            <Text>Save Form</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}
```

Render field function component

```
   class RenderField extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <Fragment>
            <Texto>{this.props.label}</Texto>
            <TextInput
              onChangeText={this.props.input.onChange}
              {...this.props.input}
              keyboardType={this.props.type}
            />
          </Fragment>
        );
      }
    }
```

So how can I call `this.prop.reset()` on screen change using class component with react navigation v6 ?

Comment: I can't see clear your component's architecture, but I wonder why do you need to reset the state of the component, wouldn't be easier to just render the same component in the new page? 

I don't get why this component is out of the routing

Comment: @Manjar I need to clear it because I have some forms where render it conditionally,so if there is any other form with a same input name it can  conflict and adding the same value to another field, so if the user go back screen I want to clear the state of the form that he was using , got it ?

Comment: But it seems like you have a "global" state I can't follow where that state hold

Comment: @Manjar I edited it , I'm holding it on my render field component